# Should I add my employer where I am still in probation to my resume?

Tags: job-search, probation

I am currently having a job for two months, and I am still in my three-months probation period. Knowing that there is probability that my employment would not be extended, I am planning to apply to some other companies.

The question is, should I add this employment to my resume?

Comment: Depends on the reason you are not being kept on.  You should only list experience and contacts that paint the picture you want to be seen.  Leaving experience off because you performed poorly will of course bite you in the rear end also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a temporary contract with only the possibility of extension (not guaranteed) then yes, you should have no issues applying to other places and mentioning your current employer. No-one should expect you to limit your options when your future employment is not guaranteed.

Personally, I've done this after 4 months even when I had a permanent contract (subject to passing probation, which I didn't even finish). Employers understand that some places are just bad, and if you have a good CV and can explain to them any issues you are having they will understand. Similarly, I expect they would understand your situation if you simply explained it to them.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the company culture.  In my current position I started as a temp and it was assumed that we would stay on and have the contract extended unless they came to us and said that our contract would be up.

When adding the position to your resume you need to ask two questions
- Does it look better to have this job listed then a three month employment gap?
- Does this job add anything to my resume and experience?

As far as I have been able to tell, recruiters and hiring managers much prefer to see a resume with no gaps in them.  I would absolutely add the job to my resume if I could find any positive benefit from the time I spent there even if it was a new product or system or methodology.

Answer (score -1):

From experience I have found that good news travels faster than bad news.
Meaning you probably would have heard by now if you get or have gotten an extension. You could always ask for a Status update from your Manager.

But I wouldn't add them to my resume for the following reasons:

- You haven't been an full employee there yet
- Not getting an extension means they might not paint a desirable picture
- Don't add every reference you have
- Doesn't sound like an addition to your resume
- Employees often ask why you want to leave telling them I don't think my employment will be extended isn't the best thing to say

The fact that you haven't been informed of your status leaves me to believe that you either won't be hired, this of course might not be the case depending on your Company's way of doing things.